# Why there is open my connection in Ef core datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action, ef-core-2.0

I am a novice. Take it easy on me. 
this is code for  my action

```
[HttpGet]
    public async  Task<IActionResult> EditRole(string id)
    {
        var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if(role == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Role with Id = {id} cant be found";
            return View("NotFound");
        }

        var model = new EditRoleViewModel()
        {
            Id = role.Id,
            RoleName = role.Name
        };

        foreach(var user in userManager.Users)
        {
            try
            {
                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    model.Users.Add(user.UserName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

and when check my user is in this role throw this  exception

> {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."}

[image]

Comment: So what does `roleManager.FindByIdAsync` or `userManager.IsInRoleAsync` do?

Comment: RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager; these are @nvoigt

Comment: Which line threw the exception? It probably has a StackTrace that will tell you.

Comment: I think you need to call SaveChangesAsync() after every Add() or perform an AddRange() and then call SaveChangesAsync()

Comment: if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
on this line throw exception @nvoigt

Comment: i dont have add or modified any thing just read from database @MestreDosMagros

Comment: ahh ok, take the userManager.Users and put in a var outside the foreach loop, then pass the var to the foreach and try again

Comment: i think userManager.Users is not fully loading all the users from database, the there is another select being performed in the if statement, and there is the open connection problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from this:

```
 foreach(var user in userManager.Users)
        {
            try
            {
                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    model.Users.Add(user.UserName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            
        }
```

To this:

```
var users = userManager.Users.ToList();

 foreach(var user in users)
        {
            try
            {
                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    model.Users.Add(user.UserName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            
        }
```

Putting the userManager.Users on the foreach loop creates a connection to retrieve the users from the database and it is not closed until finished, then when you call userManager.IsInRoleAsync there is already a connection open in the db.

Comment: Another option is maybe call userManager.Users.ToList() to force finish the users consult on the foreach

Comment: thanks this worked
I forget this is open until to convert and execute by tolist()